# Find all first, then all second, then all third etc. elements of lists in a list

Tags: list, haskell, matrix, transpose

Working with a self-made definition of a *(9x9)* matrix described as a list of lists of `Maybe Int`s. I want to create a function that returns the *9* columns of the matrix. I want to do this something like:

```
cols :: Matrix a -> [Block a]
cols matrix = map (!! n) matrix
 where
  n = (the values 1 .. 9)
```

- Matrix is described as `[Rows]` or `[[values]]`
- Block is described as `[a]`

So I want the output to be a list of lists, where those lists are a list of the first elements of the rows, the second elements of the rows, etc etc.

I see that

```
map (!! 1) matrix
```

will return a list of the second elements of the rows, ie the second column of the matrix; but I don't know how to extend this to all the columns of the matrix in a nice function.

Comment: For the sake of reference (I realise your goal is implementing it yourself): you want to [`transpose` the list of lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html).

Comment: This is entirely true, I didn't realise transpose did this at first, but @Ami Tavroy is using the exact method I wanted to understand more about. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see that

```
map (!! 1) matrix
```

> Will return a list of the second elements of the rows, ie the second column of the matrix; but I don't know how to extend this to all the columns of the matrix in a nice function.

If this is the way you want to go, you could simply change this to

```
map (!!i) matrix
```

in

```
[map (!!i) matrix | i <- [0.. length (matrix!!0) - 1]]
```

For example

```
Prelude> let matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
Prelude> [map (!!i) matrix | i <- [0.. length (matrix!!0) - 1]]
[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

---

Of course the problem with this is that the complexity is unnecessarily high, as the complexity of `!!` is linear in its argument. Instead, you could build a recursive function as follows:

- Suppose you split each of the elments of matrix to `head` and `tail`, respectively
- Where do the `head` of  all of the elements of fit in the transposed matrix?
- What happens if you now try the same thing on the `tail` of all of the elements?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, you want to calculate the [`transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:transpose) of the matrix:

```
import Data.List(transpose)

cols :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cols = transpose
```

You can implement this in an efficient way as follows:

```
cols :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cols [] = []
cols ([]:_) = []
cols l = (map head l) : cols (map tail l)
```

This code works **only for *rectangular* matrices**. The code works as follows: if we give `cols` an empty list, or a list where the first *row* is empty, than we reached the end of the transpose, so we return an empty list.

If on the other hand there is still a list, and the first row contains one element (and since the matrix is square so do the other), we first take the `head` of all the rows as the column, and then perform recursion on the `tail`s of the rows to calculate the remaining columns.

The function works in *O(n)* with *n* the number of *elements* (not rows/columns) of the matrix. Or *O(r×c)* with *r* the number of rows and *c* the number of columns.

Comment: Nice. Out of curiosity, what would be the "haskonic" way of dealing with ragged matrices?

Comment: @AmiTavory Start by deciding what output you want for a ragged matrix, and then find a good implementation of that goal. That is, there are lots of reasonable ways to "transpose" a list of lists that's not a matrix, and you can't look for an idiomatic solution until you choose one of them.

Comment: @AmiTavory: I think the problem is indeed how you *define* a transpose of a ragged matrix. If you look columnwise to the matrix, then you see that there are gaps. How to handle these gaps?

Comment: why not like the built-in `transpose` does, by gluing them over:  `transp [] = [] ; transp xs = concatMap (take 1) xs : transp (filter (not.null) (map (drop 1) xs))`. @AmiTavory

Comment: Thank you all for your answers on the comment.